# Establishing an Entry Class for a Linked List

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have a new project where I am creating a class for an entry in a doubly linked list. I am utilizing object-oriented style, which I have limited experience with. The constructors and functions were defined in a separate file.

Header File:

```
#ifndef LISTENTRY_H_JDP
#define LISTENTRY_H_JDP

#include "DATAClass.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef DATAClass l;
typedef class LISTEntry *listptr;

class LISTEntry
{
  DATAClass data;
  listptr prev;
  listptr next;

public:
  LISTEntry();
  LISTEntry(DATAClass l);
  LISTEntry(LISTEntry &le);
  ~LISTEntry();

  LISTEntry getNext();
  void setNext();

  LISTEntry getPrev();
  void setPrev();

  DATAClass getData();
  void setData(DATAClass d);
};

#endif // LISTENTRY_H_INCLUDED
```

Implementation File:

```
#include "LISTEntry.h"

LISTEntry::LISTEntry()
{
    data = data;
    prev = NULL;
    next = NULL;
}

LISTEntry::LISTEntry(DATAClass l)   //take an item of type l and convert it into a LISTEntry
{
    data = l;
    prev = NULL;
    next = NULL;
}

LISTEntry::LISTEntry(LISTEntry &le)
{
    data = le.getData();
    prev = le.getPrev();
    next = le.getNext();
}

LISTEntry::~LISTEntry()
{
}

LISTEntry LISTEntry::getNext()
{
    return *next;
}

void LISTEntry::setNext()
{
    next = new LISTEntry;
}

LISTEntry LISTEntry::getPrev()
{
    return *prev;
}

void LISTEntry::setPrev()
{
    prev = new LISTEntry;
}

DATAClass LISTEntry::getData()
{
    return data;
}

void LISTEntry::setData(DATAClass d)
{
    data = d;
}
```

The issue is my copy constructor, LISTEntry(LISTEntry &le). So far, I receive the error:

> cannot convert 'LISTEntry' to 'listptr {aka LISTEntry*}'

I am also unsure about the get and set functions. I want them to link to new entries of the same type in the list. I guess I am having trouble with the implementation of pointers in the constructor. Can anyone help out?

Comment: In `LISTEntry::LISTEntry()`, `data = data;` is silly. Why assign a variable to itself? All you can do with this is expose a bug it `l`'s assignment operator is flawed.

Comment: is that a list or is that a node? *is confused*

Comment: This is supposed to be an entry in the list that contains the node along with pointers to link to the previous and subsequent entries in the list. EX: The DATAClass is the node, and that is inside a LISTEntry. The List is composed of list entries.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve the problem by removing the copy constructor, but this hides the problem that caused the error.

Unless `l` is poorly written (violates [the Rules of Three or Five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)), there is no need for a copy constructor or destructor in `LISTEntry`. `LISTEntry` has no special resources of its own and should be able to observe the Rule of Zero. If `l` is broken, fix `l`, do not inflict its flaws on other classes.

But this is not what you want to do for a couple reasons.

The underlying problem causing the error message is `prev = le.getPrev();` is attempting to assign a copy of the source's `LISTEntry`'s previous node to the new `LISTEntry`'s pointer to the previous node.

`prev` needs the address of a `LISTEntry`, not a `LISTEntry`.

In a linked list `LISTEntry LISTEntry::getNext()`and `LISTEntry LISTEntry::getPrev()` should almost certainly not return a copy of the node pointed at. You want to return the pointer. If you do not, you will find that iterating through the linked list is an adventure. You'll be operating on, possibly modifying, copies of nodes rather than the originals. Chaos ensues.

Change them to `LISTEntry * LISTEntry::getNext()` and remove the dereference in the `return` statement.

This solves the error, and a few more you hadn't found yet, but leaves you with a different problem, and the same one you'd have if you removed the copy constructor. You now have two `LISTEntry` with the same `prev` and `next`. This can make for an unstable list. With the copy you can blow the crap out of the original's list. Not cool. Be careful. You are actually better off NOT copying the the links and making the copy constructor:

```cpp
LISTEntry::LISTEntry(const LISTEntry &le) // make everything const until proven otherwise
{
    data = le.data; // this is a member function so it can access private variables
                    // no need for the accessor function
    prev = nullptr;
    next = nullptr;
}
```

You also need/want an  assignment operator

```cpp
LISTEntry & operator=(const LISTEntry &le)
{
    if (this != &le)
    {
        data = le.data; 
        prev = nullptr;
        next = nullptr;
    }
}
```

You should also discuss

```cpp
void LISTEntry::setNext()
{
    next = new LISTEntry;
}
```

with [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Ducky wants to know do you plan to link an existing node if you always create a new one? This will make it really hard to insert, remove and sort.

Comment: As I understand, the get and set functions are meant to link entries in the list to one another. I don't want to have any issues with constantly creating new nodes. The List itself will be another class with the insert, remove, and search functions.

Comment: @jpep23 Understood, but if you don't get the methods of this class right you will have an extremely hard time writing the other class or find yourself coming back to rewrite portions of this class.

Comment: Side note: The users of the linked list class should not be aware of any of the linked lists's internal details. They should not know `LISTEntry` exists at all. If you wall off outside access to `LISTEntry`, you can make all of its members `public` and eliminate the need for any getters and setters. The linked list class will manage the list and guarantee `LISTEntry`'s safety.

Comment: So, in the set functions, what if I just set the variables to themselves? Example: next=next. Would that be the same as with what I have in the default constructor in that it would just be for finding bugs?

Comment: Also, I want to mention that now my program is mentioning undefined references to the DATAClass file. I don't understand what's happening there since I included the header file for that in LISTEntry.

Comment: Setter should look like `void LISTEntry::setNext(LISTEntry * entry)
{
    next = entry;
}`. Now the caller can set exactly what they want as next. Unfortunately a wide open setter like this makes `next` `public` in all but name.

Comment: Shouldn't I use this->next for the set function? I was told the compiler wouldn't be able to tell otherwise.

Comment: Also, how necessary is the pointer asterisk in the get functions? For clarification.

Comment: You only need `this` if you use the same name tor a member and a local variable. It's pretty rare to need to reuse the name and I find it just leads to trouble.